# Instruction for installing an environment with Qt and Qt integration with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, installation

I want to use Qt lib but I don't know how to install Visual Studio 2008+Qt+Qtintegration. I have read some forums, that step by step tell what to download, where to download from, and then what to do. But that was for old versions of mentiond products.

I ask to Qt developers tell me the way to install these items on Windows. Any forum or site will be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get QT working with dev studio you need to install two things.

First, a copy of the QT Visual Studio Libraries. 
And the QT Visual Studio Addin.

- http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008
- http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in

Download the QT sdk, and install it. It usually installs into a folder like

```
c:\qt\4.6.2
```

Then, install the visual studio addin. The addin should add (At least) two new things to Visual Sutdio. A new "Qt" project in the Create New Project Wizard, and a Qt menu.

Qt supports building your project against multiple builds of Qt, so the first thing you need to do is go to the Qt menu, and point it to the directory you installed the Qt SDK to. It all went well it should auto populate with c:\qt\4.6.2

Then, use the Wizard to create a new Qt project in Visual Studio.

If you are creating your first Qt project in Visual Studio this way, there is no need to fiddle with .pro files or doing any kind of "stuff" outside Visual Studio to get a project going. The Visual Studio addin sets up the workspace to do all the pre-compiles needed by the Qt build environment.

--

Note: The Qt SDK at this URL

- http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/sdk-windows-cpp

comes with the MinGW runtine for GCC, and Qt Creator embedded. This is no good for Visual Studio. This build installs to a folder like

```
c:\Qt\2010.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Just want to add, that "Qt Creator" as a compleat tool to develop Qt aplications(with MinGW complire and other comfortable features), as you told. And that is not a bad choise as well!